# How to use self defined package

Tags: go

I have follow two simple go files

main.go

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "go-package/math"

func main() {
    xs := []float64{1, 2, 3, 4}
    avg := math.Average(xs)
    fmt.Println(avg)
}
```

mymath.go

```
package math
func Average(xs []float64) float64 {
    total := float64(0)
    for _, x := range xs {
        total += x
    }
    return total / float64(len(xs))
}
```

The file and directory structure is:

```
$GOPATH
  src
    go-package
       math
         mymath.go
       main.go
```

When I navigate to $GOPATH/src/go-package, and open the terminal and run the command: `go run main.go`, the result is printed out.

Then, I navigate to $GOPATH/src/go-package/math, and run the command `go install`, and the package successfully installed at `$GOPATH\pkg\windows_amd64\go-package\math.a`

Then I navigate back to $GOPATH/src/go-package, and remove the `math` directoy,
I rerun the command `go run main.go`, error occurs:

```
main.go:4:8: cannot find package "go-package/math" in any of:
        D:\softwareInstalled\Go\src\go-package\math (from $GOROOT)
        D:\softwareInstalled\Go\GoPath\src\go-package\math (from $GOPATH)
```

I have put the math package at `$GOPATH\pkg\windows_amd64\go-package\math.a`

I wonder why Go doesn't pick up the package from this directory.

And how can I use math.a?Where should I place it?

Comment: Why do you want to use `math.a`? The go tool doesn't use raw object files, it requires packages to build.

Comment: Thanks @JimB. I am new to Go. I thought math.a is a compiled stuff, that can be imported/used as third party thing,like Java jar files?

Comment: The prebuilt packages in `/pkg/` are just a cache. Binary only packages were introduced in Go 1.7, but other than a mention of them existing I haven't seen anyone using them. The proposal for them is here: https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/2775-binary-only-packages.md

Comment: Tip: Don't try to be fancy or special, just use the go tool like everybody else. Keep the sources and read https://golang.org/doc/code.html. You gain absolutely nothing from trying nonstandard ways.

Comment: The docs for binary only packages are here: https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Binary_Only_Packages. The only users of these are typically corporations that are unable to release source code but still want to distribute packages.

Answer (score 0):

Golang uses the source files of your imported packages. So when you wanna use the package `go-package/math` inside your main.go, you should not delete the source files from `src/go-package/math`. Leave them inside your project and everything's good.

Besides, `go get` also loads source files into your `$GOPATH/src` folder. Hope this helps.